# How can I get the phone number from a computer modem?

Tags: modem, telephony, hyperterminal, delphi, caller-id

On Windows 7 x64, Device Manager detect my modem as HDAUDIO Soft Data Fax Modem with SmartCP,
I would like to know if I can connect the landline to my modem port, and when there is a call, grab the phone number?

I need to grab the Phone Number, so it can be used on a software I'm doing.

I want the phone number of the person calling me. I'm using Delphi as my development tool.

HyperTerminal 
ATZ
- OK
AT+VCID=1
- OK

Comment: What do you mean with grabbing the phone number? Do you want the phone number of the person calling you?

Comment: This will only work with CLIP enabled.

Comment: You should state which phone number you want to retrieve. The number of the called party or the number calling party? As for Caller Id and incoming calls `+CLIP` is for cellular modems. `+VCID` or `#VCID` is used for land lines.

Answer (score 1):

This will only work if the caller has CLIP enabled.

Have a look here: http://www.activexperts.com/mmtoolkit/at/commands/?at=%2BCLIP where the describe the `AT+CLIP - Calling line identification presentation` command.
This will most probably work with your modem too.

Answer (score 0):

From [This description](http://www.engineersgarage.com/tutorials/at-commands?page=3)

6)            ATA - This command is used to answer a call. An incoming call is indicated by a message ‘RING’ which is repeated for every ring of the call. When the call ends ‘NO CARRIER’ is displayed on the screen. 
SYNTAX:         ATA(Enter)

As ATA followed by enter key is pressed, incoming call is answered.
For example,

```
RING
RING
ATA
```

I seem to remember some modems following `RING` with the incomming telephone number, when caller-id is enabled on the phone-line. For example :

`RING 01206821212`